# psycopg2: command is too large when storing large values in CockroachDB

Tags: psycopg2, cockroachdb

I'm looking to store a `~0.5G` value into a single field, but [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) is not cooperating:

```
crdb_cursor.execute(sql.SQL("UPSERT INTO my_db.my_table (field1, field2) VALUES (%s, %s)"), ['static_key', 'VERY LARGE STRING'])

psycopg2.InternalError: command is too large: 347201019 bytes (max: 67108864)
```

I've already set `SET CLUSTER SETTING sql.conn.max_read_buffer_message_size='1 GiB';`

**Is there any (better) way to store this large a string into `CockroachDB`?**

Clients will be requesting this entire string at a time, and no intra-string search or match operations will be performed.

*I understand that there will be performance implications to storing large singular fields in a `SQL` database.*

Answer (score 2):

It seems at the moment that `psycopg2` isn't capable of handling strings that large, and neither is CockroachDB. CockroachDB [recommends](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/bytes.html#size) keeping values around 1MB and with default configuration the limit is somewhere between 1MB and 20MB.

For storing a string that is several hundred Megabytes, I would suggest some kind of object store and then store a reference to the object in the database. [Here is](https://github.com/bobvawter/cacheroach) and example of a blob store built on top of CockroachDB that may give you some ideas.